# Max number of KVM guests in Centos host

Tags: centos, redhat, kvm-virtualization

On [this page](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-kvm-limits), Redhat state that RHEL 5, 6 & 7 are all limited to a maximum of 4 concurrently running KVM guests.

Other products that they offer, such as "Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization", do not have any such limits.

My question is - does this limit apply to Centos? For that matter, is the limit enforced in the RH kernels somehow, or is it just a question of what their support service covers?

Comment: Did you read footnote 1?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, both the first dot point and the note numbered 1 (strange footnote numbering there). They make me think it is only a support service thing, but I was not sure. Thus the question.

Comment: It seems perfectly and completely obvious to me, after having read it.

Answer (score -1):

It's a statement of what their support services cover, so there are no other restrictions to the max number of guests, however, their maximum number is determined by their tests on the hardware, so it is a good indication of a reasonable number of max guests for that hardware

Comment: You didn't read footnote 1 either.

Comment: I didn't read the question properly. Thanks, I've changed my answer